# Wordpress Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that was working until recently. One morning I woke up to my website being down.

I disabled the plugin and when I went to reactive it I had the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in ........../icalculator.php on line 213

Here's the line 213 and a few following it. Any idea how to correct this?

```
function mm_iching_page($_POST) {
  $_SESSION['iching_result'] = serialize($_POST);

  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is a superglobal, and is automatically available in ALL scopes. You're trying to re-assign something new to $_POST by specifying it as a function argument. Don't do that.

```
function mm_iching_page($foo)
```

would be a more appropriate choice. Using PHP core/standard variables as the names of function arguments is very bad practice. Especially for the superglobals. You're essentially overwriting what should never be changed from within user-level code.